# how to customize the tableview has shown in figure

Tags: objective-c, ipad

How to create the tableview has shown below picture
.[image]

If i created section i am missing th boarder line  what to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the UITableView to Grouped Style. Then you need 2 Sections, with no Header.

also you have to set the

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

Example Code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 2;
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
if(section == 0)
    return 1;
else
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
switch(indexPath.section)
{
case 0:
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Create a Holiday Card";
    break;
case 1:
    switch(indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Login to Photo";
        break;
        case 1:
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Create a Free Account";
        break;
    }
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: @ jussi... thanks a lot .. when i am working with this its missing th border for the section 2 row 1

Comment: Can you provide an additional screenshot?

Comment: Just decreased the heightForRowAtIndexPath its working... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

### Per example above

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;// Amount of sections
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (section == 1){
        return 2;
    }
}

- (void)tableViewUITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPathNSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
```

Comment: @ Emre Akman  When i when with section its missing the border line for the section 2.  i do attach it to the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the STYLE of that example.

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
/* also assuming your table sits on a UIViewController */

[myTableView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
[myTableView setOpaque: NO];
```